# mysql find users that haven't posted

Tags: mysql

I have a table of `users` with an `id` column and a table of `posts` that have a `user_id` column.

I'm looking to find all users that have never posted.

Pseudo Code:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
JOIN posts p 
WHERE u.id IS NEVER IN p.user_id
```

I think that I'm missing something simple here and can't find the answer. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.* 
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN posts p ON u.id = p.user_id 
WHERE p.user_id is null;
```

`LEFT JOIN` will give you those users even if they have not posted any posts, those users will have `p.user_id` equal to null. So adding `WHERE  p.user_id is null` will give you those users who never posted any posts.

Comment: Thanks, looks like you posted just before I did. Any difference between the LEFT JOIN and sub query method that you might see. Both are producing similar speed results for me.

Comment: @MinistryofChaps suggested this link to explain what is better. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query

Answer (score 1):

You can try this-

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
where u.id not in (select p.user_id from posts p);
```

Comment: Sub query, why the hell didnt' I think of that :S

Answer (score 1):

This is your solution:

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT p.user_id FROM posts p)
```

Somewhat explanatory, checks the user IDs in users that are not in posts.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a NOT IN and a subselect

```
  SELECT u.* 
  FROM users u
  where u.id  NOT IN (
    select user_id 
    from posts
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Not in

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
JOIN posts p 
WHERE u.id IS NEVER IN p.user_id
NOT IN (SELECT p.user_id FROM posts )
```